# Datatemplate in c# code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I search an option to build a datatemplate in c# code.
I had used :

```
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextBox));

        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        FrameworkElementFactory txtElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        txtElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);

        txtElement.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "test");


        dt.VisualTree = txtElement;


        textBox1.Resources.Add(dt, null);
```

But it doesn't work (it is placed at the Loaded-Method of the window - so my textbox should show the word "test" at window start). Any idea?

Comment: It Doesn't work - Does it throw an exception, is the textbox empty, is there another issue?

Comment: Here is an example of doing a ControlTemplate in SIlverlight - not quite the same but still quite similar. See if it helps you: [Dynamic ControlTemplate in Silverlight](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2010/01/dynamic-controltemplate-in-silverlight.html)

Comment: i can start the application.
i get no exception.
but my text, which i had set with setvalue is not displayed

Answer (score 8):

Each element needs to be added to the current visual tree. For example:

```
ListView parentElement; // For example a ListView

// First: create and add the data template to the parent control
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextBox));
parentElement.ItemTemplate = dt;

// Second: create and add the text box to the data template
FrameworkElementFactory txtElement = 
    new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
dt.VisualTree = txtElement;

// Create binding
Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

// Third: set the binding in the text box
txtElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
txtElement.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "test");
```

Comment: thank'S, but i doesn't understand, what you mean with the binding.

my binding is set of TwoWay...
maybee whole code?

Comment: if i set it to the binding, i can't change it later, or is that wrong?

Comment: @user1565467 I misread the details about the binding and have removed the confusing statements. Just add it to the visual tree first and the binding should work as described, assuming the PropertyPath is correct and the DataContext of the parent control is correct.

Comment: ok... i has change the code, but it doesn't work. 
but on my window is a textbox - i add the datatemplate to the resources of the textbox. i see not, what should be wrong.

Comment: @user1565467 OK. Once again, my mistake. I thought dt was the parent control but it is not. You need to create and add each element to the visual tree as you go. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: not your mistake, i had written it not good enough.


on my window is only one textbox.
this would i change per code and binding.
the problem is, that my texbox has no ".Itemtemplate" or  ".DataTemplate"

the whole task is, to change  the color of a propertygrid cell, if the input is wrong (i don't now the cell's position) but i use the test with the textbox, because it is not so complex.