# How to add Checkboxes to Listview from Code behind using C# in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I am populating a listview from code behind, why I am doing this scenario is, I need to create columns dynamically from code behind(one column,two,three....). My code looks like below

**XAML Code :**

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lvLOv" Width="400"></ListView>
```

**C# Code:**

**Output:**

[image]

But I need to place checkboxes before every row like as below(I need to do this in code behind like above code/ integrate the checkbox code in the above code). I need to place checkall option also in the header

public TestForm()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Test();
}

```
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Create Columns
        dt.Columns.Add("Initial", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        //Adding Rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("K" + i, "David" + i);
        }

        GridView gv = new GridView();


        // Create the GridView Columns
        foreach (DataColumn item in dt.Columns)
        {
            GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
            gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(item.ColumnName);
            gvc.Header = item.ColumnName;
            gvc.Width = Double.NaN;
            gv.Columns.Add(gvc);
        }

        lvLOv.View = gv;

        //Binding to Listview
        lvLOv.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Can you please let me know how can I achieve this functionality

Comment: This is *not* how to write WPF. When using WPF, we do *not* programmatically add UI elements. Instead, we use data binding and manipulate data elements. See the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information.

Comment: You have to assign `ListView.ItemTemplate`. It may not be easy in code behind ([click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14053804/1997232), [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12560249/1997232)).

Comment: Delete all that horrible code and use proper DataBinding and Data Templating.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I know but I am getting different data(with different column count). I know the columns at run time then how can I bind those columns to listview

Comment: Why is this community so abrasive?

Comment: did you solve it? I need the same,... cause I need to create dynamic gridview columns, and some of them could be checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Its really easy just do this..

In Design view (Xaml):

```
<Window.Resources> 
   <DataTemplate x:Key="Chk_Field" DataType="{x:Type GridViewColumn}">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding chk}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

In Code behind:

```
GridView gridview = new GridView();
Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
DataTemplate s = (DataTemplate)window.FindResource("Chk_Field");
gridview.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Head", CellTemplate = s });
```

By doing this you can change the celltemplate for each column in code behind..